# Why can't I type Japanese characters at the prompt in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode

I usually use Python 2, but today I'm working with a library for processing Japanese text that only works with Python 3. In Python 2, the following sort of thing works at the command line with no problems:

```
$ python2.7
Python 2.7.8 (default, Nov  3 2014, 13:46:40) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> print "歩く"
歩く
```

However, in Python 3 I can't do this. It's not that the command gives an error message, it's just that no matter how hard I try, it won't let me type the Japanese characters into the string in the first place. (Actually I see them appear on the screen, but as soon as I switch back to English mode or press enter, they disappear again.)

Note that this problem is only with entering Japanese characters at the interactive Python prompt. If I use them in a file there's no problem.

So what's going on here? Is this a bug in my particular implementation (Python3.4 installed via Macports on OS X) or is it due to some kind of design decision to do with encodings or something?

If the latter, is there something special I can do to enable Japanese input at the prompt?

Comment: I have no problem entering Japanese characters into Python 3. There could be a bug in the interaction between your input method and Python, perhaps, but there is no conscious decision to not accept your input due to encoding, *far from it*. You may need to include details about how you input Japanese here (I only get as far as counting and greeting in Japanese, and I never try and write any).

Comment: Presumably you are using [one of these input methods](http://redcocoon.org/cab/mysoft.html)?

Comment: Python 3 has much, much, much better support for unicode than python 2. I'm tempted to blame your shell: try out IPython as well and see if that works.

Comment: @MartijnPieters yes, Kotoeri hiragana input mode. (The standard way to enter Japanese text on a Mac.)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I'm running OS X 10.10.2; I opened Python 3.4.2 and used Romanji, Hiragana and Katakana modes to enter text into the interactive prompt. In all cases switching implementation modes or pressing enter left the input on the screen.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you - it's useful to know it's something weird about my system rather than a Python 3 thing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is your Python installed via Macports?

Comment: @Nathaniel: my python was installed using [buildout.python](https://github.com/collective/buildout.python), which means for the most part the same libraries are used when MacPorts. I switched from MacPorts to homebrew ages ago, however.

Comment: The Idle Shell might work better for you (or it might be worse and never show the characters).

Comment: Looks like this is not limited to Japanese input. It appears to be the *input method switch*, and a MacPorts issue with that: [python 3.4.2 typing cyrillic fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29230725)