# python 3.4.2 typing cyrillic fails

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x, keyboard, cyrillic

This is a really bizarre problem. I don't know where to start. I am on OS X, Terminal.app, UTF-8. If I type cyrillic in bash, it works fine. If I open python2.7, I can type cyrillic characters fine. If I open python3.4 (macports), I can type

```
print( '
```

but when I switch my keyboard to cyrillic, none of my cyrillic keypresses register. I can still type numerals and other symbols, but not the cyrillic letters. What is going on? How can I get the console to register cyrillic keypresses?

I can pipe cyrillic text to python3.4. This is just a problem with the console.

EDIT: I also have a macports installation of python3.2, and it fails in the exact same way.

Comment: Someone reported just the same thing with Japanese the other day. Also using Macports. I'd say it is the Macports readline library mucking this up, as it works just fine for me using my buildout.python build as well as the one from Homebrew.

Comment: See [Why can't I type Japanese characters at the prompt in Python3?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29145279); I cannot dupe this but it looks like the same issue.

Comment: Thanks Martijn! That definitely looks like a similar problem, although my characters never appear in the first place. I'll look into a different installation.

Comment: You can try and use the [buildout.python project](https://github.com/collective/buildout.python) to build a whole set of Python binaries. That's what I use and they work great, no input issues whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Martijn Pieters who solved this issue for me (see comments above). This does appear to be an issue with Macports. I did not want to use homebrew for other reasons, but the buildout.python project seems to do the trick.